# Selecting all records that start with particular letters or numbers

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently using this PHP code to pull in records from a database for records starting with a 1,A,B or C so that I can sub-divide a very long list of 2500+ records.

```
'where' =>
        "record_approved='1' AND {$data['database']['database_field_title']} LIKE 'A%' OR {$data['database']['database_field_title']} LIKE '1%' OR {$data['database']['database_field_title']} LIKE 'B%' OR {$data['database']['database_field_title']} LIKE 'C%'",
```

Now this code works fine.

However can I reduce this? I do not really want to have OR's multiple times for 2,3,4,5... as well as each letter.

Or do I?

Also following on from this, I have an issue with the following code.

```
$this->_catRecords1 = array();
            $this->DB->build(
            array(
            'select' =>
            $data['database']['database_field_title'].', primary_id_field, record_static_furl, record_dynamic_furl',
            'from' => $data['database']['database_database'],
            'where' =>
            "record_approved='1' AND field_46 NOT IN ('17', '18', '19', '20', '30', '140', '141', '142', '143', '144', '145', '146', '147', '148', '149', '150', '151, '152', '153', '154', '155', '156', '157', '158', '159', '160', '161, '162', '163', '164', '165', '166') AND LEFT({$data['database']['database_field_title']}, 1) IN('A','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9')",
            'limit' => array(0, 3000),
            'order' => $data['database']['database_field_title'].' ASC'
            ) );
            $otherData = $this->DB->execute();
            while ( $row = $this->DB->fetch($otherData) )
            {
            $row['title'] = $row[$data['database']['database_field_title']];
            $row['_skipUpdateDynamic'] = true;
            $row['url'] = $this->registry->ccsFunctions->returnDatabaseUrl($data['database']['database_id'], 0, $row);
            $this->_catRecords1[] = $row;
            }
```

field_46 is a column containing a number between 1 and around 200.

Without the

```
AND field_46 NOT IN ('17', '18', '19', '20', '30', '140', '141', '142', '143', '144', '145', '146', '147', '148', '149', '150', '151, '152', '153', '154', '155', '156', '157', '158', '159', '160', '161, '162', '163', '164', '165', '166')
```

the code is functioning correctly. So I must be doing something wrong there.

Just getting a pretty generic MySQL error saying there is an error in my code!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not just use a [string function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_left) and IN()?

```
WHERE record_approved='1' AND LEFT(your_string, 1) IN('A','1','B','C')
```

here we use the `LEFT` function that takes the string and then the number of characters... so in this case it would be `LEFT(string, 1)` to get the first character in the string.. and then say that it matches the fields A, 1, B, C.. that is what the `IN()` does.

**NOTE:**

if you are storing just a number in a column (record_approved) i would recommend saving it as an INT.. as a general rule of thumb you should store data as its intended datatype.

Comment: Thanks - works perfectly. Appreciate your help

I assume that if you wanted the first 2 characters, you would simply change 1 to 2 and the strings to 'AB','1','AC','AD'

But would that still include say the 1?

Was wondering how one might sub-divide records starting with A into two groups, say records starting with AA - AM & AN to AZ

Ought to add that I do not need to do that, just curious, so I can learn :)

Comment: @lan To do a second letter you need a second left statement with a 2 for the number of characters and a second in with the filtering.. So you would have` LEFT(string, 1) = 1 AND LEFT(string, 2) in(an, ad... Etc)`

Comment: To subdivide the data as you described you would need to do that in your select.. So like SELECT CASE WHEN LEFT(string, 2) <= 'AM' THEN string ELSE '' END... and then the same thing for the other range :) if you want more details I can edit my answer and I'll provide some visuals

Comment: Thanks. Trying to learn. So appreciate your help :)  Have rapidly approaching 3,000 records that I need divide up. Better than a very long list LOL

Comment: What might be wrong with  "record_approved='1' AND field_46 NOT IN ('17', '18', '19', '20', '30', '140', '141', '142', '143', '144', '145', '146', '147', '148', '149', '150', '151', '152', '153', '154', '155', '156', '157', '158', '159', '160', '161', '162', '163', '164', '165', '166') AND LEFT({$data['database']['database_field_title']}, 1) IN('A','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9')",  Getting a database error. field_46 is a valid field. Thanks

Comment: @Ian well what is field_46? is it a column?

Comment: @Ian can you post the schema of your table and the full query in your question?

Comment: @Ian try just selecting field_46 to see that you have access to it.. without using the where.. just as a debug test